# Check strong name of .net assembly on deployment machine

Tags: .net, .net-assembly, strongname

This is the scene... I have deployed a dll on a remote machine which has the required .NET framework but not Visual Studio and tools. On the same day, I created 3 builds with different strong names for the dll. I need to verify the strong name on the remote machine but I don't have the luxury of getting a copy of that dll. How do I do this without the SDKs on the remote machine?

Comment: Can you copy some exe to that server?

Comment: @WouterdeKort, No... that is not allowed. I need to use the tools available on that machine. They have command prompt and powershell. I need to check nearly 400 dlls even though I know only 1 is to be checked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run the following PowerShell command where you should insert the path and name of the assembly:

```
powershell.exe -command "[System.Reflection.AssemblyName]::GetAssemblyName('mydll.dll').FullName"
```

Comment: I used this along with some more powershell command (I'm a noob to powershell) and got what I wanted. Dankeschon.

Answer (score 1):

Above will not work - return same result no matter if assembly is strong named or not. it can be only delay-signed to pass that test.

```
Get-ChildItem *.dll | % { 
    Write-Host "ps: " -NoNewLine
    [System.Reflection.AssemblyName]::GetAssemblyName($_).FullName
    Write-Host "sn: " -NoNewLine
    sn -vf $_
}
```

```
ps: MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=11a11111a1111111
sn: MyAssembly.1.1.13.dll is a delay-signed or test-signed assembly

ps: MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=11a11111a1111111
sn: MyAssembly.1.1.15.pre.dll is valid
```